# Dependencies outside of Apache NiFi must not use SNAPSHOT versions

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm new to NiFi and I'm trying to develop my first custom processor.

I'm following documentation(s)/tutorial(s) on *how to create one*,  and here I am:

1. generated maven skeleton project for nifi-processor; (✔)
2. added some simple implementation in the `onTrigger(...)` method; (✔)
3. failing to build `.nar`. (x)

Whenever I'm executing `mvn clean package` either within any sub-directory of the custom processor project structure (`nifi-artifactBaseName-nar` or `nifi-artifactBaseName-processors`) or in the root directory of the project, I get this:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.2.1:enforce (enforce-maven-version) on project nifi-myfirstcustomrprocessor-nar:   
[ERROR] Rule 3: org.apache.maven.enforcer.rules.dependency.RequireReleaseDeps failed with message:
[ERROR] Dependencies outside of Apache NiFi must not use SNAPSHOT versions
[ERROR] com.giorgi.tutorials:nifi-myfirstcustomrprocessor-nar:nar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR]    com.giorgi.tutorials:nifi-myfirstcustomrprocessor-processors:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT <--- is not a release dependency
```

Anything I'm doing wrong? any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.

When creating a custom processor project (or just any maven project), version `1.0-SNAPSHOT` is generated by default (disregarding of whether you create it from command-line, IDE, or etc.), and that's NOT OK for NiFi custom processor - you should NOT use `SNAPSHOT` for versioning your custom processor artifact.

I just changed `1.0-SNAPSHOT` to `1.0` and everything worked fine - `.nar` has been built.